# How to use a variable as a parameter of a module?

Tags: python, loops, variables, module, package

*Note: I am completely new to python and programming in general.*
I am essentially using modules and packages for analysis purposes. Is it possible to put a variable as a argument of a module?

Let say I have 3 files:

```sh
a.csv 
b.csv 
c.csv
```

I have for each file a scaling number that I have saved in a tuple named `scale` [1,2,3,].

I would like to use a module that takes the file and its scaling number as arguments.
It look like this

```
import module as mo
mo.function -scale 1 -input a.csv > output.csv
```

Instead of writing this numerous of times, I have 96 files, I would like to use a loop to do that for me.

Thank you very much for your help!

### --
I hope it is better now

Comment: Remember to use correct code formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by using a variable as a parameter of a module, but I assume that `scale` and `input` are arguments of `mo.function`.

What I would do in such case is loop through the files and the associated scaling numbers

```
import module as mo

my_files = ['file1','file2','file3']
scaling_numbers = [5, 6, 7]

for file, s in zip(my_files, scaling_numbers):
    mo.function(inp=file, scale=s)
```

Edit:

If you have 96 files, perhaps it will be useful for you to use the module `os`:

```
import module as mo
import os

directory = 'path/to/folder/with/your/files/'

my_files = [directory + file for file in os.listdir(directory)]
scaling_numbers = [5, 6, 7]

for file, s in zip(my_files, scaling_numbers):
    mo.function(inp=file, scale=s)
```

If you also have a list output files where you want to save the data, just include it in the zip:

```
for file_in, file_out, s in zip(input_files, output_files, scaling_numbers):
    mo.function(inp=file_in, out=file_out, scale=s)
```

Comment: yes, scale and input are arguments of mo.function

Comment: Sorry, I do not have all the vocabulary to describe this..

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out. I tried to make a loop using the tuple but had not clue how to add the files..

Comment: I forgot to mention the output in the function.. Sorry

Comment: That's perfect, thank you. Yes, I already use the os.listdir function. Zip will be really helpfull!

Answer (score 0):

Could you better explain your question?

Comment: Done, hope it is better!

Comment: Yes it is better, I would help you but someone has already described the correct answer